# Some animal is turning over my lawn roots. How to fix it?

Tags: lawn, pest-control, lawn-repair, pest-damage

I have a backyard open to a hill and without a fence. Recently, I have had some animals or an animal that have turned over my lawn almost every day last week. I found some grubs under the lawn, so grubs may be causing them to break my lawn.

How do I repair my lawn? Is it just OK to reseed over the rooted lawn?

Also, how can I prevent the animal from doing it again?
I installed a cat repeller, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: Armadillos in Texas do damage like that. Not easy to keep out without a fence.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing it would apparently be a matter of not having a tasty grub population.

That will probably help the turf health, given the habits of many grubs living under lawns eating the grass roots...if the food isn't there, the animal won't come dig up the lawn to get the food. If you just fend off the animal eating the grubs, your lawn will be grub central.

Answer (score 1):

A cat wont do this, so a cat repeller wont work.

If you are treating it like a lawn, then you need to level it out somehow. A roller would work well, perhaps you can rent one. Then just sprinkle seed on top and tap them down with the back of a rake or a spade, gently.

To prevent that animal from redoing its job, you need to identify it. Perhaps a camera through your window, overnight.  Or ask your neighbours.